# Android independent animations

Tags: android, animation, view, sliding

How to make two independent animations for the same view.

Scenario would be like:

View is sliding from left to right, and user might click back button which means that the same view should fade out during sliding animation.

I can't achieve this, because when I start fade-out animation, sliding is being interrupted and moved to it's final position.

AnimationSet is not an option in this situation I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ObjectAnimator for Android SDK 14+ or the library NineOldAndroids for below. Here is an example how it would look (a View sliding 300px to right and additionally fades out as soon as back is pressed)

```
private Animator fadeOut;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final View view = findViewById(R.id.button);

    //we prepare the fadeOut-Animator to be started onBackPressed
    fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ALPHA, 0);
    fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

    //we prepare and start the slide-Animator
    final Animator slide = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_X,300);
    slide.setDuration(3000);
    slide.start();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    fadeOut.start();
}
```

*I don't recommend to do something else with the back-button than navigating back.